# Is "M2MqttDotnetCore" is compatible for asp.net core 6.0?

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

In the nuget package, i could see "M2MqttDotnetCore",
which is for MQTT client based on M2Mqtt 4.3.0 for .NETCORE 3.1.

But I have used this in asp.net core 6.0 project. which is compatible.

My question is whether does impact any in future if i shipped to the production for long term use ?

Any suggestion about "M2MqttDotnetCore" using it on top of the dotnet core 6.0

I have used this "M2MqttDotnetCore" in my asp.net core 6.0 project. So far no issue or warning message.
as per the description which is for MQTT client based on M2Mqtt 4.3.0 for .NETCORE 3.1.

But i have used it in the .NETCORE 6.0, i am able to use it.

Will it impact any in future, if i ship "M2MqttDotnetCore" along with asp.net core 6.0.

Is anyone used "M2MqttDotnetCore" the same in asp.net core 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

That should be okay, assuming you're referring to .NET 6. All .NET Core 3.1 packages are generally compatible with .NET 6.  You can verify its compatibility through the official NuGet site, https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2MqttDotnetCore#supportedframeworks-body-tab.